# Using subclass variables in base class methods

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I wonder what is a common way of using subclass variables(`self.sub_resource` in this example) in base class methods?

The version 1 and 2 seems works the same, but version 1 have less code, but `self.sub_resource` is highlighted in pycharm with `Unresolved attribute reference 'sub_resource' for class 'Base'`

So which variant is preferable? Any other pros/cons?

```
# Version 1:

    class Base():
        def __init__(self):
            self.base_resource = 'Base.resource'

            print('Base.__init__')

        def predict(self):
            print('Base.predict() start')

            self.forward()

            print('Used in Base.predict():', self.base_resource)
            print('Used in Base.predict():', self.sub_resource)

            print('Base.predict() end')

        def forward(self):
            raise NotImplementedError

    class A(Base):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.sub_resource = 'A.sub_resource'

            print('A.__init__')

        def forward(self):
            print('A.forward() start')
            print('Used in A.forward():', self.base_resource)
            print('Used in A.forward():', self.sub_resource)
            print('A.forward() end')

    print('-' * 60)
    a = A()
    a.predict()

# Version 2:

    class Base():
        def __init__(self, sub_resource):
            self.sub_resource = sub_resource
            self.base_resource = 'Base.resource'

            print('Base.__init__')

        def predict(self):
            print('Base.predict() start')

            self.forward()

            print('Used in Base.predict():', self.base_resource)
            print('Used in Base.predict():', self.sub_resource)

            print('Base.predict() end')

        def forward(self):
            raise NotImplementedError

    class A(Base):
        def __init__(self):
            self.sub_resource = 'A.sub_resource'

            super().__init__(self.sub_resource)

            print('A.__init__')

        def forward(self):
            print('A.forward() start')
            print('Used in A.forward():', self.base_resource)
            print('Used in A.forward():', self.sub_resource)
            print('A.forward() end')

    print('-' * 60)
    a = A()
    a.predict()
```

Comment: In the second example, why do you set the attribute in the subclass then invoke the superclass to immediately reset it? In the first, there's nothing to guarantee that every subclass ever sets the attribute, so the warning is correct. If the base class can't work on its own it should be [_abstract_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), and the requirements for subclasses should be expressed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2  is correct way of doing it. This allows a subclass extend the Base class without declaring `sub_resource` property.

The interpreter needs to be sure that the property exist. That's why pycharm highlighted the line in version 1. Subclass value will take precedence over base class during execution.

It's ideal to declare all the accessed property in the base class, then override it in the subclass where necessary.